# white-space:nowrap on pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have an element set to `a {display: inline-block;}`. I added a pseudo element `a:after {display: inline-block;}`. Now, if I set `white-space: nowrap` one the parent element I expect that both `a` and `a:after` will stay on the same line all the time. Is that statement correct? as I'm having some difficulties to achieve desired effect.

Comment: Please, can you share the enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The code I working on now is a part of large HTML file. The answer below shows exactly what I am doing. Thanks @Praveen.

Comment: The *question* alone should explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `:pseudo` elements do not work like this! They do not inherit text-styles from their parent from their parent.

```css
a {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;}
a:after {display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; content: 'Hello, how are you?'; width: 50px; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello!</a>
```

Comment: Could you suggest any work around to keep both elements in the same line ? What I need is to hide the element rather that break the line.

Comment: It is unclear what the question really is, and it is unclear what question this addresses and how. It makes an incorrect statement: pseudo-elements do inherit properties. Besides, `white-space` by its nature affects all the textual content of an element, including child nodes.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The CSS rule `white-space` on parent element doesn't affect the **pseudo** elements for sure!